# JUnit Test Cases for Generalized Methods

Tags: java, generics, junit

Excuse me for the potential redundant question but I have been learning about generics recently, and have sort of been at a loss as to how they should be tested.

Here is my code for a method to find the minimum value in a collection:

```
public static <T> T min(Collection<T> c, Comparator<T> comp) {
  if (c == null || comp == null) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Collection or comparator is null.");
  }
  if (c.isEmpty()) {
     throw new NoSuchElementException("Collection is empty.");
  }
  Iterator<T> itr = c.iterator();
  T min = itr.next();
  if (itr.hasNext()) {
     for (T i : c) {
        if (comp.compare(i, min) < 0) {
           min = i;
        }
     }
  }
  return min;
}
```

And this is the minimal test case I have prepared for this method:

```
public class SelectorTest{

  @Test
  public void min() {
     Comparator<Integer> intSort = new IntegerSort();
     Integer[] test = {2, 8, 7, 3, 4};
     int expected = 2;
     int actual = Selector.min(test, intSort);
     Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

  public static class IntegerSort implements Comparator<Integer> {
     public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
     }
  }
```

}

The compiler error that I'm receiving from this code is as follows:

```
required:java.util.Collection<T>,java.util.Comparator<T>
found: java.lang.Integer[],java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Integer>
```

Clearly the argument I am passing through the test case isn't what should be passed through, but the way I am thinking of it is like this: I am passing an integer array through which is a collection, and I am giving it a specific comparator for integers, as the min method requires.

How should I fix this test case to effectively work in this manner, and to not only work with Integers, but any sort of Collection as the min method is capable of doing?

I've never successfully written generalized test cases before so I am at a loss as to how I can go about this.

Thank you!

Comment: integer array does not implement [java.util.Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with generics. You cannot pass an array as a parameter, when the method expects a Collection. Arrays do not implement the Collection interface. If you would pass an instance of an ArrayList, it should work just fine.

Comment: That would make more sense. Thank you!